# Database created in Access 2013 not opening in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I created a database in Access 2013. it includes forms and macros. When I am trying to open the same database in 2007 version, it is not opening.

Can someone help me with the reasons and possible solutions to this?

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: "it is not opening" is not a useful problem description. What exactly happens?

Comment: You should provide more information. But probably your database got controls or something available only for Access 2013 or higher, that Access 2007 cannot understand. Try to open the database in Access 2013 and then save it as compatible with Access 2007. If you have any control or something not compatible with Access 2007, a wizard will pop up and tell you what's wrong.